# Image passed from an API not displaying in a pageview container swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, sdwebimage

I am working on an iOS application which interacts with an API using alamofire and swiftyJSON. In this api I get a bunch of values returned and one of them is images. the Images returned comes in form of an array but i am able to iterate through the array and display a single image. To make the application more advanced, I decided to implement **UIPageViewController** class in my application. I called the API function and tried to pass my images into view controllers.

**List of things in my storyboard**

1. A UIPageView
2. A UiViewController with a UIImage embeded into it.

I have my codes fine to the best of my knowledge but when I run the application nothing happens on in the console. Below is my codes.

```
protocol ProductImagesPageViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func setupPageController(numberOfPages: Int)
    func turnPageController(to index: Int)
}

class ProductPageVC: UIPageViewController {

    weak var  pageViewControllerDelegate: ProductImagesPageViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        dataSource = self
        delegate = self

    }


    func configureImg() {
        let productId = ProductServices.instance.selectedProduct?.id
        ProductServices.instance.findIndividualProducts(id: productId!, completion: { (success) in

            if success {
                ProductServices.instance.productDetails.forEach({ (productDetail) in

                    let images = productDetail.productImg.count

                    if images > 0 {

                        for image in 0..<(images) {

                            let imageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: PRODUCT_IMAGE_VC)
                            self.controllers.append(imageVC!)

                        }
                    }

                })
            }
        })
    }

    lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var controllers = [UIViewController]()


        let productId = ProductServices.instance.selectedProduct?.id
        ProductServices.instance.findIndividualProducts(id: productId!, completion: { (success) in

            if success {
                ProductServices.instance.productDetails.forEach({ (productDetail) in

                    let images = productDetail.productImg.count

                    if images > 0 {

                        for image in 0..<(images) {

                            let imageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: PRODUCT_IMAGE_VC)
                            controllers.append(imageVC)

                        }
                    }

                })
            }
        })



        self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.setupPageController(numberOfPages: controllers.count)

        return controllers
    }()



    func turnToPage(index: Int)
    {
        let controller = controllers[index]
        var direction = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward

        if let currentVC = viewControllers?.first {
            let currentIndex = controllers.index(of: currentVC)!
            if currentIndex > index {
                direction = .reverse
            }
        }

        self.configureDisplaying(viewController: controller)

        setViewControllers([controller], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func configureDisplaying(viewController: UIViewController)
    {
        for (index, vc) in controllers.enumerated() {
            if viewController === vc {
                if let imageVC = viewController as? ImagesVC {

                    imageVC.configureImage(productIndex: index)

                    self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.turnPageController(to: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// MARK: - UIPageViewControllerDataSource

extension ProductPageVC : UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        if let index = controllers.index(of: viewController) {
            if index > 0 {
                return controllers[index-1]
            }
        }

        return controllers.last
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let index = controllers.index(of: viewController) {
            if index < controllers.count - 1 {
                return controllers[index + 1]
            }
        }

        return controllers.first
    }
}

extension ProductPageVC : UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController])
    {
        self.configureDisplaying(viewController: pendingViewControllers.first as! ImagesVC)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
    {
        if !completed {
            self.configureDisplaying(viewController: previousViewControllers.first as! ImagesVC)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my ImageVC code

```
class ImagesVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    func configureImage(productIndex : Int) -> Void {

        ProductServices.instance.productDetails.forEach { (productImg) in

            if productImg.productImg.count > 0 {
                imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: productImg.productImg[productIndex]!) )
            } else {
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image_not_found")
            }
        }

    }}
```

This is my HeaderImageView code

```
class HeaderImageVC: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
}

extension HeaderImageVC : ProductImagesPageViewControllerDelegate {
    func setupPageController(numberOfPages: Int)
    {
        pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
    }

    func turnPageController(to index: Int)
    {
        pageControl.currentPage = index
    }
}
```

I have no idea why the code is not working but further codes would be supplied on request. Thanks.

**According to suggestion**

```
var images = (ProductServices.instance.productDetails.first?.productImg) 

    lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var controllers = [UIViewController]()

        if let images = self.images {
            for image in images {
                let imageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: PRODUCT_IMAGE_VC)
                controllers.append(imageVC)
            }
        }



        self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.setupPageController(numberOfPages: controllers.count)

        return controllers
    }()
```

this still returns empty

Comment: Are you setting image on main thread?

Comment: I have no idea if setting on main thread could be a problem but I didnt specify the thread

Comment: print for current thread or put breakpoint to check on what thread you are setting image. Alternatively, You could specify thread to rule out thread issue.

Comment: It’s not running on the main thread

Comment: Please set image on main thread. DispatchQueue.main.async { // Set Image }

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: something wrong in this function : self.controllers.append(imageVC!)  please make it correct . and please explain what does do this function.

Comment: You want to show multiple images of one item, right ?

Comment: Yes of the selected items. I have a variable to check the id of the selected items. So if the item is selected I want to display the images of the item

Comment: your code  `lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = {` will always return empty array !! As it has webservice to call which is async task and it will not wait to finish it, so you are not able to see any thing !!

Answer (score 1):

**problem**

```
lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var controllers = [UIViewController]()

    // IT WILL NOT WAIT TO FINISH IT
    let productId = ProductServices.instance.selectedProduct?.id
    ProductServices.instance.findIndividualProducts(id: productId!, completion: { (success) in

        if success {
            ProductServices.instance.productDetails.forEach({ (productDetail) in

               // NO USE OF productDetail as it is already returned 

                let images = productDetail.productImg.count

                if images > 0 {

                    for image in 0..<(images) {

                        let imageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: PRODUCT_IMAGE_VC)
                        controllers.append(imageVC)

                    }
                }

            })
        }
    })


    // controllers.count is 0

    self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.setupPageController(numberOfPages: controllers.count)

    return controllers
}()
```

if you observe above code and you should debug it, then you will find that `controllers` is empty Because it is async task and compiler will not wait for finish `findIndividualProducts` task to complete  it will return the empty array which you have define so outcome is your controller has nothing to show !!  -> Make sense

Solution is that simple you can create method that will set the call the API `findIndividualProducts` and assign it to the  `controllers`  now the controller is simple plain property.

Hope it is helpful

**EDIT**

First create one method and call it from view did load or view will appear whatever suits you

```
 private func getAllControllers () {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var controllers = [UIViewController]()

    // IT WILL NOT WAIT TO FINISH IT
    let productId = ProductServices.instance.selectedProduct?.id
    ProductServices.instance.findIndividualProducts(id: productId!, completion: { (success) in

        if success {
            ProductServices.instance.productDetails.forEach({ (productDetail) in

               // NO USE OF productDetail as it is already returned 

                let images = productDetail.productImg.count

                if images > 0 {

                    for image in 0..<(images) {

                        let imageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: PRODUCT_IMAGE_VC)
                        controllers.append(imageVC)

                    }


  self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.setupPageController(numberOfPages: controllers.count)
  self.controllers = controllers
                }

            })
        }
    })

}
```

and remove lazy block from your controller property

`var controllers: [UIViewController] = []`

Comment: sorry can I dont quite understand. can you explain further?

Comment: @King in simple words  your lazy `var controllers: [UIViewController] = {` has API Call now before the api response comes , the `return controllers` statement  executes so your view controller is empty and you won't able to see anything Hope it is clear

Comment: yes. but how do I now pass the images into the controller

Comment: @King You have to create one method, And put that code inside it  and call it from viewDidLoad or viewwillappear whatever suits you!! , So when the api call completed you can call     `self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.setupPageController(numberOfPages: controllers.count)` and also assign `controllers`

Comment: I have a function there saying `configureImg()` I deleted the API call int he controller but calling the `configureImg()` in viewDidLoad does nothing. returns blank pages too

Comment: @King after that change your code with  `var controllers: [UIViewController] = []`

Comment: If you don’t mind please edit your answer to reflect what you are saying.  Thank you